# On textfield focus set session[:something] in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails I have a form with text fields inside it. When I click on one of them I want to set session[:something]. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by making an Ajax call back to the server.

Answer (score 0):

What's the purpose of setting the session here?

Are you trying to pass some information back to the server?

If yes, then you can add hidden field(s) within the form, that you can set programmatically when you respond to the click. The data within these fields will then be POSTed back to the server when the form is submitted.

If not, then you can just use cookies. In which case you can use something like http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie or http://pastie.org/1986824 to work with cookies. Note that cookies are also available on the server side (but are not meant to be for storing large amounts of data).

If you need to pass back information to the server immediately, then use an AJAX call. Some examples are available here (using jQuery): http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/5-ways-to-make-ajax-calls-with-jquery/.